How to send data through a writable Dockerode stream instance in Nodejs?
I'm using Nodejs to interact with the Docker API using the Dockerode npm module, i saw some examples of how to attach a shell to the terminal and send input with the keyboard, but how can i send data through the stream? like a simple confirmation string "y\n" to automatize install wizards
I tried something like:
const exec = container.exec({
   Cmd: ["pacman", "-Syu"],
   AttachStdout: true,
   AttachStderr: true,
   Tty: true
})

let output;
const stream = await exec.start();

stream.on("data", data => {
   output += data.toString()   
})

stream.write("y\n")

// ....

